# foreach with xml and switch

Tags: php, xml, foreach, switch-statement

I have an XML file which look like this:

```
<services>
  <service>
    <code>MODULE_1</code>
    <name>Regular</name>
    <price>14.85</price>
  </service>

  <service>
    <code>MODULE_2</code>
    <name>Express</name>
    <price>22.50</price>
  </service>

</services>
```

`$result` retrieves the file from another server. My code looks like this:

```
$methods = array() ;    
$xmlQuotes = new SimpleXMLElement($result)  ;

foreach($xmlQuotes as $quote) {
    $add = 0 ; $f = 0 ;
    switch ($quote->code) {
        case  "MODULE_1" ;
        if ((in_array("Regular", $this->allowed_methods))) {
            $add = MODULE_1_HANDLING ; $f = 1 ;
            $id = "m_1";
            $cost = $quote->price;
            $description = $quote->name;
        }
        break;

        case  "MODULE_2" ;
        if ((in_array("Express", $this->allowed_methods))) {
            $add =  MODULE_2_HANDLING ; $f = 1 ;
            $id = "m_2";
            $cost = $quote->price;
            $description = $quote->name;
        }
        break;
    }

    if (($cost > 0) && ($f == 1)) {
        $cost = $cost + $add ;
        $methods[] = array('id' => "$id",
                           'title' => "$description",
                           'cost' => "$cost");
    }
}

$this->quotes['methods'] = $methods;
```

And this is all good until the final point - when I'm using the code, the `$methods` array doesn't return correct `$cost` and `$description` for it's matching `$code`, but instead returns the price and description of my first module. It looks something like this:

```
MODULE_1: Regular: 14.85
MODULE_2: Regular: 14.85
```

I'm going crazy here 'cause I obviously don't know what I'm doing so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in your second `((in_array("Express", $this->allowed_methods)))` condition. If it returns false and previous condition `if ((in_array("Regular", $this->allowed_methods)))` returned true, then cost and description will always contain only their first values.

Comment: no, that's not it. I just tried removing the if (leaving only the case) but it didn't do the trick, it's still the same.

Comment: BTW, this might be confusing - the in_array actually checks for settings in the database, not the ones from the xml file.

Comment: Okay, let's debug that. Just put `echo $cost . ', '` before `if (($cost > 0) blabla` and provide me what it echoed.

Comment: I tried `echo $description .': '.$cost .'< /br>';` and it's also correct. So, must be something with constructing the methods array

Comment: I'm kinda confused, it must to work. What would be an output of var_export($methods) inside the loop (for every stage) and after the loop? It is really strange.

Comment: uhm... OK, you just hit my breaking point. What should I add and where? How do I get that output? :)

Comment: Put var_export($methods) before the foreach closing "}" and after it (befor "$this->blabla...").

Comment: I have no idea what it returned, I can't read that :)
[link]http://codepad.org/vJhJUrvC

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the entire point... In essence, this is what I have:
[link]http://codepad.org/VKWGwtuB and this is the output I'm trying to get: [link]http://codepad.org/7t7WKE32

Comment: Dude, there is something in how do you output the result. Because $methods array has a data you wanted (http://joxi.ru/tzozUdg5CbDJPnvBUB0).

Comment: Man, thanks for the efforts, I really appreciate it. You actually made me think and I found an error further down in my script - turned out I wasn't using the array output properly...

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code without those `if`-statements, then `var_dump($methods)`, result:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant MODULE_1_HANDLING - assumed 'MODULE_1_HANDLING' in /in/dTOdQ on line 24  
Notice: Use of undefined constant MODULE_2_HANDLING - assumed 'MODULE_2_HANDLING' in /in/dTOdQ on line 33  

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "m_1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Regular"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(2) "14"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "m_2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Express"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(2) "22"
  }
```

Experiment with it here: http://3v4l.org/dTOdQ